# Pandas date_range and leap years

Tags: python, pandas, date-range, leap-year

When running this code:

```
a = pd.date_range("1959-12-09 00:00:00", "2013-12-09 12:00:00", freq = "365D6H")
weekDays = [dt.datetime.weekday(d) for d in a]
df = pd.DataFrame({"Date": a, "Jour": weekDays})
df.head(6)
```

I'm getting:

```
0 1959-12-09 00:00:00     2
1 1960-12-08 06:00:00     3   * 
2 1961-12-08 12:00:00     4
3 1962-12-08 18:00:00     5
4 1963-12-09 00:00:00     0
5 1964-12-08 06:00:00     1   *
6 1965-12-08 12:00:00     2
```

and so problems with leap years. 
How could I do to have exactly one calendar year between dates in spite of leap years ?

Comment: You want to add exactly one to the year number plus six hours?  Or do you just want to increment the year by one?  I'd say a calendar year is defined properly if you use `freq='1A'`... but maybe you can elaborate?

Comment: I added six hours hoping to have the exact birthday each year (leap years included) because I got a wrong result with "365D", a year being 365.25... With "1A" I get each year exactly but on the 31st December, which is not the birthday of interest!

Answer (score 2):

Rather than use `date_range`, you could create this using a list comprehension:

```
In [11]: pd.to_datetime(["%s-12-09 %s:00:00" % (y, (6 * h) % 24)
                             for h, y in enumerate(xrange(1959, 2014))])
Out[11]: 
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[1959-12-09 00:00:00, ..., 2013-12-09 12:00:00]
Length: 55, Freq: None, Timezone: None
```

*The frequency is None, since this isn't a regular frequency... if you try and add a numpy year and a numpy hour you'll see:*

```
In [21]: np.timedelta64(1, 'Y') + np.timedelta64(6, 'h')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-6a7f3e5b3315> in <module>()
----> 1 np.timedelta64(1, 'Y') + np.timedelta64(6, 'h')

TypeError: Cannot get a common metadata divisor for NumPy datetime metadata [Y] and [h] because they have incompatible nonlinear base time units
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer is correct but I would like to know why is pandas not taking account of the leap years in my example. With a different startdate (for example: "1941-01-04") I get a correct answer but not with "1959-12-09".